# FFPLAY - How VB6 code hit Maximise

Tags: ffmpeg

I use VB6 Shell to run video's with FFPLAY but on Windows 7, the video is too big on the screen and have to drag the video over and click Maximize.  Windows 10 don't have that problem, it seems to automatically fill the screen.

so how can VB6 "click" the Magnimise button ?

Comment: Add the `-fs` option in `ffplay` for full screen. Does that do what you want it to?

Comment: thanx guy, I knew about -fs but I hoped to get Max to work somehow